# mock a library and run unit test

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock a library using jest.
Function "requestAuthorization" is just a swift function. The library 'my-health-library' uses Native Modules to access the "requestAuthorization" method.

Test file:

```
import MyHealthLibrary, { type } from 'my-health-library';


jest.mock('my-health-library', () => {
    return {
      MyHealthLibrary: {
         __esModule: true,
          default: {
             requestAuthorization: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('the response')),
             type: type
                }
            };
          }
     });

it('Testing to see if Library works', () => {
    let read = [type.heartRate]
    let write = [type.heartRate]

    expect(MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization(read, write)).toBe(true)
  })
```

This test keeps failing with **"The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables."**.
I could mock my function "requestAuthorization" but how do i mock the type???

The "type" is just an enum

```
export enum type {
  bodyMassIndex = 'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex', 
  heartRate = 'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate', 
  bodyTemperature = 'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyTemperature',  
  bloodPressureSystolic = 'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureSystolic', 
  bloodPressureDiastolic = 'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureDiastolic',  
  bloodGlucose = 'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) you can `jest.requireActual('my-health-library')`:

```js
jest.mock('my-health-library', () => {
  const { type } = jest.requireActual('my-health-library');
  return {
    MyHealthLibrary: {
      __esModule: true,
      default: {
        requestAuthorization: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('the response')),
        type
      }
    };
  }
});
```

EDIT: however, given the way you import the module (`import MHL, { type } from 'm-h-l'`) I think the export should be:

```js
return {
  __esModule: true,
  default: {
    // the default export, i.e. the MyHealthLibrary object of your import statement
    requestAuthorization: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('the response'))
  },
  type // out of the default export, to import it as desconstructed { type }
};
```